# Serilog MSSqlServer HTTPs Connection Error

Tags: asp.net-core, https, serilog

Using .net core 3.1 and serilog sql server sink, data won't get written in the database.
Enabling serilog selflog here is the following error on my console:

> Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

After creating the database manually and starting the application the "ErrorLog" table gets created inside the database (using serilog configuration) yet when it comes to inserting logs this happens.

Update

No matter what sink I'm using I face the same error!

```
[17:14:10 INF] Hello, world!
[17:14:10 DBG] Hosting starting
[17:14:10 DBG] Failed to locate the development https certificate at 'null'.
[17:14:10 DBG] Using development certificate: CN=localhost (Thumbprint: 042981E3AFFFDD00DE844A41D4437C2A52529AEB)
[17:14:10 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
[17:14:10 INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
[17:14:10 DBG] Loaded hosting startup assembly demo-log
[17:14:10 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[17:14:10 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[17:14:10 INF] Content root path: C:\Users\Omid\source\repos\demo-log\demo-log
[17:14:10 DBG] Hosting started
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T6" received FIN.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T7" received FIN.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T7" accepted.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T6" accepted.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T7" started.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T6" started.
[17:14:11 DBG] Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__69_0(SslServerAuthenticationOptions arg1, CancellationToken arg2, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
[17:14:11 DBG] Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__69_0(SslServerAuthenticationOptions arg1, CancellationToken arg2, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T7" stopped.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T6" stopped.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T6" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T7" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" accepted.
[17:14:11 DBG] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" started.
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" sending SETTINGS frame for stream ID 0 with length 18 and flags NONE
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" sending WINDOW_UPDATE frame for stream ID 0 with length 4 and flags 0x0
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" received SETTINGS frame for stream ID 0 with length 24 and flags NONE
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" sending SETTINGS frame for stream ID 0 with length 0 and flags ACK
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" received WINDOW_UPDATE frame for stream ID 0 with length 4 and flags 0x0
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" received HEADERS frame for stream ID 1 with length 341 and flags END_STREAM, END_HEADERS, PRIORITY
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" received SETTINGS frame for stream ID 0 with length 0 and flags ACK
[17:14:11 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/
[17:14:11 DBG] Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
[17:14:11 VRB] All hosts are allowed.
[17:14:11 DBG] No candidates found for the request path '/'
[17:14:11 DBG] Request did not match any endpoints
[17:14:11 INF] HTTP GET / responded 404 in 16.8270 ms
[17:14:11 VRB] Connection id "0HM29NMTJB5T8" sending HEADERS frame for stream ID 1 with length 71 and flags END_STREAM, END_HEADERS
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the Serilog for logging into the MSSQL database. Kindly use below steps.

1. Install below required packages.
   Serilog
   Serilog.Sinks.MSSQL
   Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching
2. Create a class file and write your function for logging into the database with the reference for below steps.

   ```
   using Serilog;
   using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   try
       {
          // This doesn't break/I don't get any exceptions.
         Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
         {
           Debug.Print(msg);
           Debugger.Break();
         });
           var serLog = new LoggerConfiguration()
                          .WriteTo.MSSqlServer("yourconnectionstring", 
                            "yourtablename")
                           .CreateLogger();

           Log.Logger = serLog;

           Log.Information("It works");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Log.Error(ex.ToString());
       }
       finally
       {
           Log.CloseAndFlush();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit yor configuration below;

```
Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
    connectionString: "server=SOYER\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=yourDB;TrustServerCertificate=True;integrated security=true",
    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "LogEvents", AutoCreateSqlTable = true })

        .CreateLogger();
```

the important part is *"TrustServerCertificate=True;integrated security=true"*